# How to Position Button at bottom using Autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, position, autolayout

I have UIScrollView on ViewController view and I want to keep button in bottom on scrollview. But it's not positioned as per device height like 4" and 3.5". I have applied autolayout shown in below pic.

[image]

[image]

It won't work on 3.5" inch screen. How to fix this?

Comment: try programatically, i did

Comment: thanks for reply, but programatically it's optional apple says saw in WWDC video.I was looking for solution in story board.